# How to generate MakeFile from ccmake

Tags: compiling, make, cmake, ncurses

I'm trying to install this library: https://github.com/fpeder/XKin

I cloned it into an xkin folder then I did the following:

```
cd xkin
mkdir build
cd build
ccmake ..
```

Then a terminal based GUI pops up that says `EMPTY CACHE`. So, I press `c` and it then configures and gives me this:

```
 CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE                 Debug                                                                                                                                                                                                      
 CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX             /usr/local                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 OpenCV_DIR                       /usr/share/OpenCV                                                                                                                                                                                          
 libfreenect_DIR                  /usr/local/share/libfreenect
```

I dont know where to go from here. I've checked the build folder and bunch of files were created but none where I can do `make`.

Here's the `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 2.6 )
project( XKin )

set( VERSION 1.0.0 )
set( PACKAGE_NAME ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} )

set( CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} )
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED COMPONENTS core imgproc highgui )
find_package( fftw REQUIRED )
find_package( libfreenect REQUIRED )

set( CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug )
set( CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "-g" )
set( CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O3" )
set( CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO "-O2 -g" )

configure_file( "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/config.h.in" 
            "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/config.h" ) 

include_directories( "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}" )

add_subdirectory( lib )
add_subdirectory( tools )
add_subdirectory( demo )
```

Let me know if anything else is needed and I'll provide.

Answer (score 0):

It seems once you configure the `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` to `debug` then press `c` a couple of times then pressing `g` generates the `MakeFile`.

Answer (score 0):

**You have to do the following commands:**

cd xkin

mkdir build && cd build

cmake ..

**Then if you want to change the cmake configration you do**

ccmake .

**Makefile would be present in the build directory.**

make -j4

make install